# how do you pronounce the contraction what've you in been doing?

Tags: pronunciation

how do you pronounce the contraction "what've you" in "what've you been doing?" Does it sound like what of you, what v'you, or something else?

Since we're at it, can you tell me if these contrCTIONS are pronounced these ways?

what've you = what v'you done/ what of you done
where've you been = where v'you been/ where of you been
how've you done it = how v'you done it/ how of you done it

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I teach English as a Second Language to adults. When teaching connected speech, I would tell my students to say, "What have you been doing?" as "wa-duv-iu-bin-doo-wing?" or more casually, "wa-cha-bin-doo-wing?"
(Ontario, Canada, May, 2017)

Comment: Hello, Catherine. ELU, targeted at linguists/proficient Anglophones, expects answers that reflect accepted usages/practices, such as the IPA, rather than subjective suggestions.